# Oozie Spark (2.x) action is always getting stuck at accepted state

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-spark-2.0

When I run the spark job through oozie it always getting stuck at the accepted state. I followed the [hornwork doc](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_spark-component-guide/content/ch_oozie-spark-action.html) to set up the spark2 libraries.

When I use oozie shell action for the same spark job it works perfectly fine and through the spark-submit from edge node as well with the same spark opts.

Below is my workflow.xml

```
<global>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
            <value>${queueName}</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</global>
<credentials>
    <credential name="HiveCreds" type="hive2">
        <property>
            <name>hive2.jdbc.url</name>
            <value>jdbc:hive2://${hive2_server}:${hive2_port}/default</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hive2.server.principal</name>
            <value>hive/${hive2_server}@DOMAIN</value>
        </property>
    </credential>
</credentials>
<!--spark action using spark 2 libraries -->
<start to="SPARK2JOB" />
<action name="SPARK2JOB" cred="HiveCreds">
    <spark
        xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <master>${master}</master>
        <mode>${mode}</mode>
        <name>${appName}</name>
        <class>${mainClass}</class>
        <jar>${hdfsJarLoc}${uberJar}</jar>
        <spark-opts>--num-executors ${noOfExec}
        --executor-cores ${execCores}
        --executor-memory ${execMem}
        --driver-memory ${drivMem}
        --driver-cores ${drivCores}
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=${dynamicAllocation}</spark-opts>
        <arg>${sourceFilePath}</arg>
        <arg>${sourceFileName}</arg>
        <arg>${outputFilePath}</arg>
        <arg>${outputFileDir}</arg>
    </spark>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="errorHandler" />
</action>
```

My `job.properties`

```
jobTracker=HOST:8050
nameNode=hdfs://HOST:8020
hive2_server=HOSTNAME
hive2_port=10000
queueName=default

# Standard useful properties
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
#oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true

ooziePath=/path/

#oozie.coord.application.path=${ooziePath}

## Oozie path & Standard properties
oozie.wf.application.path=${ooziePath}
oozie.libpath = ${ooziePath}/Lib
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark2

master=yarn-cluster
mode=cluster
appName=APP_NAME
mainClass=MAIN_CLASS
uberJar=UBER_JAR
noOfExec=2
execCores=2
execMem=2G
drivMem=2g
drivCores=2
dynamicAllocation=false
```

I checked the oozie spark2 libraries I have all the jars that are in the `/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/jars/`

My oozie lib :

```
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/azure-keyvault-core-0.8.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/azure-storage-5.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/guava-11.0.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.2.6.3.0-235.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/hadoop-azure-2.7.3.2.6.3.0-235.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/hadoop-azure-datalake-2.7.3.2.6.3.0-235.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/joda-time-2.9.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/json-simple-1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/okhttp-2.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/okio-1.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/oozie-hadoop-utils-hadoop-2-4.2.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20180116141700/oozie/oozie-sharelib-oozie-4.2.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar
```

Below is the ERROR stack :

It will get stuck in the ACCEPTED state (something like below) for an hour or so

```
 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - Application report for application_1537404298109_2008 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

**STDOUT :**

```
INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - Application report for application_1537404298109_2008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-09-20 14:49:15,158 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - Application report for application_1537404298109_2008 (state: FAILED)
2018-09-20 14:49:15,158 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1537404298109_2008 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1537404298109_2008_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://hostname:8088/cluster/app/application_1537404298109_2008 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User:yarn not allowed to do 'DECRYPT_EEK' on 'testkey1'
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1537468694601
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://hostname:8088/cluster/app/application_1537404298109_2008
     user: username
2018-09-20 14:49:16,189 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - Deleted staging directory

<<< Invocation of Spark command completed <<<<<< Invocation of Spark command completed <<<

Hadoop Job IDs executed by Spark: job_1537404298109_2008


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, Application application_1537404298109_2008 finished with failed status
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1537404298109_2008 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1233)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:314)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:235)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

**STDERR :**

```
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1537404298109_2008 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1233)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:314)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:235)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I tried all the possible solutions found in the hortonworks community and stack for the same type of issue, but nothing worked for me. If you need any other information to help me I'm more than happy to add it to the question.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User:yarn not allowed to do 'DECRYPT_EEK`

DECRYPT_EEK is permission which is in Ranger which need to be given to a user.
If u are the ranger admin do it else contact admin.

Comment: I noticed that error, but why is it not working through oozie spark action but works with shell action and from the spark submit ?